# how to display images and text on it in listview flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to display a images and text in listview. Data is parsed and set it in model class. can you please help me out. Below is my class.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client.get('url here');

  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}

// A function that will convert a response body into a List<Photo>
List<Photo> parsePhotos(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
  return (parsed["data"]["categoryList"] as List)
      .map<Photo>((json) => new Photo.fromJson(json))
      .toList();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    return new MyHomePage();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new FutureBuilder<List<Photo>>(
      future: fetchPhotos(new http.Client()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? new PhotosList(photos: snapshot.data)
            : new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Photo> photos;

  PhotosList({Key key, this.photos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(child: _buildList(context)
        ),
    **//Able to display images but want to show text from list on images.**
        new Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
          child: new Text('DAILY WALLPAPER',
              style: new TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  //Showing the images in listview
  ListView _buildList(context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: photos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int) {
          return new CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: photos[int].url);
        });
  }
}

class Photo {
  final int catID;
  final String title;
  final String url;
  final String thumbnailUrl;
  final String description;
  final String webstiteURL;

  Photo(
      {this.catID,
      this.title,
      this.url,
      this.thumbnailUrl,
      this.description,
      this.webstiteURL});

  factory Photo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Photo(
      catID: json['category_id'] as int,
      title: json['category_name'] as String,
      url: json['category_img'] as String,
      thumbnailUrl: json['thumb_img'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
      webstiteURL: json['website_url'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build your layout in `itemBuilder` property of `ListView`. If you want to place the text on the image the best layout widget is `Stack`.

See the following in order to get the layout system of flutter: 
https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/

and for all the available layout widgets see:
https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/

and Stack: 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Something like this:

```
new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Positioned.fill(
      child: new FadeInImage(
        placeholder: new AssetImage('placeholder.png'),
        image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(photos[int].url),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        fadeInDuration: new Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        fadeInCurve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ),
    new Positioned(
      top: 10.0,
      left: 10.0,
      child: new Container(
        child: new Text(photos[int].title)
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: can you please help me out to start the design using stack. i am new in flutter so.

Comment: i have checked the code.it shows only single text. i want to generate it dynamic. look like, images and text will come from json array and need to display it in listview. Can you please help me?  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by single text? in the code you need to change 'your test' to photos[int].title to make it dynamic.

Comment: i have tried look like this but it gives me error.

return new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: photos.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int) {
          return new CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: photos[int].url);
        }
        ),
          new Positioned(
            top: 10.0,
            left: 10.0,
            child: new Container(
                child: new Text(photos[int].title)
            ),
          ),
       ],
    );

Comment: yes i tried the current code but i give me error on CachedNetworkImage.
The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider.

Comment: Hi, You are right. You need to user 'new CachedNetworkImageProvider(photos[int].url)' instead. I'll edit the code.

Comment: Now everything is good but getting the error while passing index for get the url.
When pass the int getting error like below: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'
in below line:
image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(photos[int].url),

Comment: Change the name of your variable from int to index

Comment: i have not declared any variable for int. i have to pass the size of list in that place.but how to pass the list size in place of int.

Comment: can you please help me out to display the text and images as seen in screenshot? i have multiple data so can not generate it using stack. please give me your skype id or other way to discuss about this?