# State Management to hold the data in flutter for sqlite database using sqflite plugin?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, android-database, sqflite

I am making an app in flutter using sqflite for the SQLite database, in that app, users can save their financial transaction information like name, amount. date,etc. I am trying to display all the records saved between two dates in the SQLite database, for that, I have created a form taking two dates.

I have made the following function for getting records from my database:

```
Future<List<expense>> getExpenseDateWise() async {
final db = await database;

var expenses = await db
    .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= ? AND DATE(DATETIME) <= ?',
['$FromDate','$ToDate']);



List<expense> expenseList = List<expense>();

expenses.forEach((currentExpense) {
  expense expenses = expense.fromMap(currentExpense);

  expenseList.add(expenses);
});

return expenseList;
}
```

Is this function correct for the purpose?
Now I don't know how to display using this function on another screen.
I want to display those transactions like it is displayed in the following image:
[image: show]
I don't know how to display it like it is displayed in the image.

Edit 1:

After trying the method provided by @Usama Karim i implemented that like this:

```
return Provider(
    create: (context) => dateWiseTransactions(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: '$finalFrom - $finalTo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
  final expense = await Provider.of<dateWiseTransactions>(context, listen: off).getExpenseDateWise()
),);
```

It was giving me the following error:

```
error: Expected to find ')'. (expected_token at [finance_manager]   lib\viewExpenses\dateWise.dart:37)
error: Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.  (positional_after_named_argument at [finance_manager] lib\viewExpenses\dateWise.dart:37)
error: Expected an identifier. (missing_identifier at [finance_manager] lib\viewExpenses\dateWise.dart:37)
```

So I tried a different approach:

```
class _dateWiseViewState extends State<dateWiseView> {

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
DatabaseProvider.db.getExpenseDateWise().then(
      (expenseList) {
    BlocProvider.of<ExpenseBloc>(context).add(SetFoods(expenseList));
    },
  );
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String finalFrom = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(widget.fromDate);
  String finalTo = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(widget.toDate);

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("$finalFrom - $finalTo"),
  ),
  body: Container(
      child: BlocConsumer<ExpenseBloc, List<expense>>(
          builder: (context, expenseList) {
            return ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  expense expensess = expenseList[index];
                  return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                          border: Border.all(width: 2,color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Text(
                              expensess.name
                                  .substring(0, 1)
                                  .toUpperCase(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            expensess.name ?? "Title",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            "Amount: ${expensess.amount.toString()}"
                                "\nDate: ${expensess.pickedDate}\n"
                            ,style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                          }
                      )
                  );
                },
              itemCount: expenseList.length,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(color: Colors.black),
                );
          },
        listener: (BuildContext context, expenseList) {},
       ),
     ),
   );
  }
}
```

[image: datewiseList]

But this also doesn't work as in the image please help me with it.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: you can check this tutorials its very easy https://codesundar.com/flutter-list-view-example/  and https://medium.com/@ekosuprastyo15/how-to-create-listview-in-flutter-dynamic-d824dc86f470

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display images and text on it in listview flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855236/how-to-display-images-and-text-on-it-in-listview-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for your replies,@DhavalParmar  but I am not looking for building ListView but I am looking for finding the records from the database and then displaying them in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for this purpose.

Make a separate class and add this method in that class

```
class Expense {
Future<List<expense>> getExpenseDateWise() async {
final db = await database;

var expenses = await db
    .rawQuery('SELECT * FROM EXPENSES WHERE DATE(DATETIME) >= ? AND DATE(DATETIME) <= ?',
['$FromDate','$ToDate']);



List<expense> expenseList = List<expense>();

expenses.forEach((currentExpense) {
  expense expenses = expense.fromMap(currentExpense);

  expenseList.add(expenses);
});

return expenseList;
  }
}
```

Wrap the material class with the Provider and instantiate your class like this

```
Provider( 
create: (_) => Expense() 
child: Material( ...
```

Now you can use this method anywhere inside your app. To get the method use the following

```
 final expense = await Provider.of<Expense>(context, listen: off).getExpenseDateWise()
```

Now use `expense` variable which has `List<expense>` data

Comment: Hello @Usama Karim, thanks for the reply I tried your method it wasn't working, I have updated the question please help me, thanks

Comment: I have written the error in the code as well please help me

Comment: Can you show your code with my approach? Show the class you made and how you are using it?