# Flutter: Image BoxFit.cover doesnt work in Stack

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I want two images stack over each other in a gridview and both showing a

### image witch covers the whole tile.

But when i add the stackwidget, the Image behaves like there is no

> fit: BoxFit.cover

in its build method.

### build method of my GridView:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widgetsList.length != 0) {
      return new GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: widgetsList,
      );
    } else {
      return Container();
    }   
}
```

### Gridtile (widget in widgetsList):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new CustomImage(compareTime: lastUpdatedPictureTime),
        new CustomImage(compareTime: lastUpdatedIconTime)
      ],
    );
  }
```

### build method of my CustomImage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var img = imageBytes != null
        ? Image.memory(
            imageBytes,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        : Text(errorMsg != null ? errorMsg : "Loading...");
    return new Container(child: img);
  }
```

When i use no stack and only use one CustomImage per Gridtile it works.
So maybe this is a bug?

Comment: i would try with `Positioned` - most likely with `Positioned.fill`

Comment: @pskink yes, that works :) thx

Comment: sure, youre welcome

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to add this line inside your Stack widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      new CustomImage(compareTime: lastUpdatedPictureTime),
      new CustomImage(compareTime: lastUpdatedIconTime)
    ],
  );
}
```

This worked for me :)

Comment: Love u so much bro