# Flutter Row with two container with centered image and text above it. Like in image attached

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create Row with two containers with centered image and text above image also centered.
Like in image attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yrmG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
class ExampleDesign extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 180,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 5,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 120,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 3,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text('Image'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('Some text centered'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 60,
                      width: 120,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 3,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text('Image'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('Some text centered'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget using this post [How to to display text over the images in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136826/how-to-to-display-text-over-the-images-in-flutter) which returns an image above and a text below, Wrap two of these widgets using a Row. That should work.