# Is it possible to Draw a Text over an Image File in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is the code I have been using, the problem with this is sometimes in iOS the text goes and out side of the image and cuts . I want to the text to wrap properly within the image in the bottom right corner.

P.S This is not an UI issue... I want to draw the Text on the Image FILE and use it for further purposes, not just on UI.

```
Future<File?> drawTextOnImage() async {
        final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
        // Capture a photo
        final image = await _picker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.camera,
            maxHeight: 366,
            maxWidth: 550,
            imageQuality: 50);
        final position = await locationManager.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
        if (image != null) {
          var decodeImg = UIImage.decodeImage(File(image.path).readAsBytesSync());
          final TextToDraw =
              'Lat: ${position.latitude}\nLong:${position.longitude}';
          var stringWidth = 10;
          var stringHeight = 10;
          final chars = TextToDraw.codeUnits;
          for (var c in chars) {
            if (!UIImage.arial_14.characters.containsKey(c)) {
              continue;
            }
            final ch = UIImage.arial_14.characters[c]!;
            stringWidth += ch.xadvance;
            if (ch.height + ch.yoffset > stringHeight) {
              stringHeight = ch.height + ch.yoffset;
            }
          }
    
          if (decodeImg != null) {
            UIImage.drawString(
                decodeImg,
                UIImage.arial_14,
                decodeImg.width - stringWidth,
                decodeImg.height - stringHeight,
                TextToDraw);
    
            var encodeImage = UIImage.encodeJpg(decodeImg, quality: 100);
    
            var finalImage = File(image.path)..writeAsBytesSync(encodeImage);
    
            return finalImage;
          }
        }
    
        helper.ToastFlutter('Problem Fetching Image, Please Try again');
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: DUPLICATE of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136826/how-to-to-display-text-over-the-images-in-flutter

Comment: Are you trying to write a text to an image and save it as a file? instead of displaying it in the UI?

Comment: @landfire13224 yes I want to write a text in the image file and use that file for other purposes.

Comment: @CoderAddy Please read the question carefully before marking it as duplicate .. I want to draw the text on the image file.. its not an UI Question.

Comment: Bro use this plugin maybe it can help , https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro

Comment: @CoderAddy this plugin does it when user does in mannually I want to do in the background by code.