# How to wrap text and image on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I want make this

[image]

```
Wrap(
   textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
       children: [
          Text(
            _items[1]['text'],
            softWrap: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            style: GoogleFonts.notoNaskhArabic(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 25,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
          ),
          Text(
            _items[1]['text'],
            softWrap: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            style: GoogleFonts.notoNaskhArabic(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 25,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red
            ),
          ),
      ],
)
```

I wanted to wrap Text and image like photo, but the code turns out to be like this
This wrong

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it briefly ? Is like you want text on top of image?

Comment: Yes, i want to top image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51136826/how-to-to-display-text-over-the-images-in-flutter check this out

Comment: No, I mean. I want like the photo above, open the text above the photo.

Comment: I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtay6.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RichText` with `WidgetSpan` for non text.

```dart
 RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: "A"),
      WidgetSpan(
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
        child: Icon(Icons.av_timer),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: "B"),
    ],
  ),
  ),
```

More about [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Comment: Glad to help, explore the link for more

Comment: may i ask 1 more? How to use the builder inside TextRich.
so no need to write code one by one

Comment: You can create a list of string which you already have(i think), Now you can loop/map the list and add a widgetspan on the end.

Comment: I'm use for childreen inside children for loop, success. Thanks very much